# Create context menu inside JfxPane

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I recently started a JavaFX project, and I've a question: how can i create a context menu inside a JfxPane ?

Where can i found an example ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good tutorial:
[PopupMenu in JavaFX 2](http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/popupmenu-in-javafx/)

(especially the part about **Using JavaFX Popup Menus inside JFXPanel**)

Comment: Thanks for you response. I've seen, but does not clearly explain how to perform a "setContextMenu (contextMenu)," with reference to a jfxPane